# How to read files from phone memory and memory card in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me

I am trying to create a music player in J2ME. I want to read all mp3 files from phone memory and memory card and add it to list. How to retrieve these .mp3 files?

Comment: Better u use the FileConnection API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [this](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/fileconnection/) document for go through files and folders

for reading files in memory card,
In many device you can search by E:\
and for phone memory you can search by C:\

See following links for help

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2ME/FileConnection.htm

http://www.coderanch.com/t/230849/JME/Mobile/file-browse-ME