# Create Image in SD Card or Phone Memory

Tags: java-me

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read files from phone memory and memory card in J2ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798404/how-to-read-files-from-phone-memory-and-memory-card-in-j2me)

i am working on camera capturing app in J2ME.
i want to Store images in SD card, and if SD Card is not available then it will copy data in Phone memory.

How can i achieve this??

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6829384/491978) link, it will help you.

Comment: Hey Thanks Mihir. As i have created on sample app. when i am running it is asking for some permition. what is that?? and how can i stop that??

Comment: you need signing certificate for stopping that.